# Where should the text of the network command output appear?

Tags: noflo

I recently added the ability for a FBP runtime that I am building to send the network protocol commands output and error. When using app.flowhub.io for the client, the error message shows up in a message window but I don't see the message that accompanies the output command when it is sent. The websocket frame sent to the noflo ui from my runtime looks like:

```
{"protocol":"network","payload":{"type":"message","message":"Hello"},"command":"output"}
```

Where should I expect to see the message text for an output command?

Answer (score 0):

The network output and errors should show in the right hand panel, under the runtime connection info. You may need to press the eye icon to open it.

However I believe only strings are supported.

Comment: Interesting. I did not see the output message in the right hand panel when I used Chrome as the browser (Version 43.0.2357.124 m). I then tried Firefox (Version 36.0) and the message did show up in the right hand panel.

Comment: That is interesting indeed. If you Inspect Element in Chrome, is the data found in the DOM? Could be a Z-index issue. If you can reproduce this, feel free to file a bug at https://github.com/noflo/noflo-ui